# jQuery.remove() is going crazy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple slider **using jQuery and no other plugins**.

The animation works, but when removing the first slide (to move it at the end), `.remove()` unexpectedly removes **ALL** the slides.

This is the code (snippet shows the exact issue):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var AnimateGallery = function(item)
    {
        $(item).animate({left: "-=1"}, 20, 'linear', function()
        {
            // I tried to debug, testing if $(item) caught all the slides,
            // but it doesn't.
            $(item).attr("data-off", $(item).offset().left + $(item).width());
            $(item).attr("data-out", Boolean($(item).offset().left + $(item).width() < 100).toString());

            if(parseFloat($(item).attr("data-off")) < 0)
            {
                $(item).remove();
                // ^^^^ This one unexpectedly removes all the slides when the first one meets condition
            }
            else
                AnimateGallery($(item));
        });
    };

    $(".mp-gallery")
        .find(".mp-gallery-item")
        .each(function()
    {
        var $el = $(this);

        AnimateGallery($el);
    });
});
```

```css
div.mp-gallery
{
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;

    border: 1px solid black;

    background-color: #333;

    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;

    font-size: 0;

    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;

    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.mp-gallery-item
{
    display: inline-block;

    width: calc(100% / 3);

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    vertical-align: middle;

    font-size: 12pt;

    position: relative;
}
div.mp-gallery-item
{
    height: 100px;
}
div.mp-gallery-item-image
{
    cursor: pointer;

    height: 100%;
}
div.mp-gallery-item-text
{
    padding: 2%;

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    position: relative;
    top: -50%;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    opacity: 1;

    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mp-gallery">
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-1">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: burlywood;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-2">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: darkgreen;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-3">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: darkseagreen;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-4">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: cadetblue;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-5">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: coral;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                   Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-6">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: gainsboro;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I don't know why is this happening, I just wanted to remove the first slide, append a cloned one to the end and loop like that when the condition (left margin is met) triggers.

I'm using jQuery 2.1.4

Comment: It sounds like `data-off` is `< 0` for all your elements. Have you done any debugging to find why this may be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by removing it, you are pushing the other elements over, triggering them to get removed as well

Comment: `$(item)` is the single element, `data-off` is not 0 for all elements as tested in the console window.

@AndrewBrooke I don't know why would that happen, and can't find a solution either...

Comment: Look at this fiddle, by setting the item to hidden instead of removing it, it doesn't remove the others https://jsfiddle.net/7wdvjuxe/ I'm not sure how to remedy the issue though

Comment: By doing that lots and lots of elements will be created and animated all at once...

Comment: I know, but I'm not sure how to fix that. This just shows that by removing the one item the other ones go "out of bounds" and get removed as well

Comment: I thought the same thing, and noticed that **if I remove the elements using their** `data-slideid`**, slides 1, 3, and 5 are removed** while the others remain :| This is the weirdest thing...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all the items appear to be removed at the same time is due to the items shifting to the left as their left sibling is removed. This moves each item past 0, one after another, triggering the remove method.

One solution is to absolute position the items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AnimateGallery = function(item) {
    $(item).animate({
      left: "-=1"
    }, 20, 'linear', function() {
      $(item).attr("data-off", $(item).offset().left + $(item).width());
      $(item).attr("data-out", Boolean($(item).offset().left + $(item).width() < 100).toString());
      if (parseFloat($(item).attr("data-off")) < 0) {
        $(item).remove();
      } else
        AnimateGallery($(item));
    });
  };

  $(".mp-gallery")
    .find(".mp-gallery-item")
    .each(function(index) {
      var $el = $(this);
      $el.css("left", $el.width() * index); /* Added this */
      AnimateGallery($el);
    });
});
```

```css
div.mp-gallery {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.mp-gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12pt;
  position: absolute; /* Changed this */
}

div.mp-gallery-item {
  height: 100px;
}

div.mp-gallery-item-image {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
}

div.mp-gallery-item-text {
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mp-gallery">
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-1">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: burlywood;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-2">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: darkgreen;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-3">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: darkseagreen;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-4">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: cadetblue;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-5">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: coral;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                   Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mp-gallery-item" id="slide-6">
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-image" style="background-color: gainsboro;">

                </div>
                <div class="mp-gallery-item-text">
                    Image Text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I agree with @Fraser Crosbie , but you shouldn't remove the slide, just reset it's left setting, and take the 'AnimateGallery($item);'  out of the conditional.  Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/x9fkqLph/1/